# How to extract particular values from a dataframe col and put them in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I have a dataframe consisting of a column of strings. I want to extract the place, date, and race number from one column.

Dataframe:

```
- S.no.            FileName
- 0.     Albany17NOV19sectionalRace1.csv
- 1.     Albany22NOV19sectionalRace4.csv
- 2.     New York1NOV19sectionalRace7.csv
- 3.     Aquis Park Gold Coast27NOV19sectionalRace2.csv
```

Desired dataframe:

```
- S.no.   Place                     Date     Racenumber
- 0.     Albany                    17NOV19    Race1
- 1.     Albany                    22NOV19    Race4
- 2.     New York                  1NOV19     Race7
- 3.     Aquis park Gold Coast     27NOV19    Race2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by;

1. `digit` followed by `Nondigit` and `digit` that is say `17NOV19`

**or**

2. `sectional`

**or**

3 special character `.`

After split drop all rows that have None as values and any others not wanted. Can rename columns if you needed to

```
    df=df.FileName.str.split('(\d+\D+\d+)|(sectional)|(\.)', expand=True).dropna(1).drop(columns=[4,6,11,12])
print(df)
        

          

                    0        1      8
0                 Albany  17NOV19  Race1
1                 Albany  22NOV19  Race4
2               New York   1NOV19  Race7
3  Aquis Park Gold Coast  27NOV19  Race2
```

Comment: This kinda works but the dates being divided as you can see in your example 17 Nov got split in Albany1 and 7Nov19.

Comment: Me bad. Made eidts. Basically had forgotten to put `+`  on the first `\d`

Comment: Let me know if ok, or need more assistance. Happy to help

Comment: Works great! thanks a lot mate. I just need your advice on where i can learn these expressions '(\d+\D+\d+)|(sectional)|(\.)' .

Comment: As i got one more col which contains name like this [6 MISS CIRCLEWORK (3)] and i want to extract first number and last number which in this case will be "6" and "3".

Comment: There are several places. These are regex expressions. Try https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enAU821AU821&ei=hJS0X6yIGcCc4-EPltqJ-AM&q=regex+data+science+cheat+sheet&oq=regex+data+science+cheat+sheet&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAE6BAgAEEc6CQgAEMkDEBYQHjoHCCEQChCgAVDuhQFY8acBYKGrAWgAcAJ4AIAB7gKIAcgbkgEFMi04LjSYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis2sX5kovtAhVAzjgGHRZtAj8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: I will find more examples and text send through. However search on google regex experessions in python or pandas you will get lots

Comment: If happy, please accept the answer. For the question `As i got one more col which contains name like this [6 MISS CIRCLEWORK (3)] and i want to extract first number and last number which in this case will be "6" and "3"` depends on what you want, can try `df.text.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True)`or `df.text.str.extractall('(\d+)')` where `text` is the column

Answer (score 0):

A regex function should do the job:

```
import re


def split_string_to_groups(s: str):
    temp = re.compile("([a-zA-Z\s]+)([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)(sectional)(Race[0-9]+)(\.csv)")
    res = temp.match(s).groups()
    return res

print(split_string_to_groups("Albany17NOV19sectionalRace1.csv"))
print(split_string_to_groups("Aquis Park Gold Coast27NOV19sectionalRace2.csv"))
```

Output:

```
('Albany', '17NOV19', 'sectional', 'Race1', '.csv')
('Aquis Park Gold Coast', '27NOV19', 'sectional', 'Race2', '.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as the other answers, but it still accomplishes the job:

```
extract_info = {
    'Date': lambda x: x.str.findall('\d.+?\d{2}').str[0],
    'Place': lambda x: x.str.findall('^.+?(?=\d)').str[0],
    'Racenumber': lambda x: x.str.findall('Race\d+').str[0]}

df = df.FileName.agg(extract_info.values())
df.columns = extract_info.keys()

print(df)

      Date                  Place Racenumber
0  17NOV19                 Albany      Race1
1  22NOV19                 Albany      Race4
2   1NOV19               New York      Race7
3  27NOV19  Aquis Park Gold Coast      Race2
```